# SQL DISTINCT selection not working with not equal

Tags: php, sql, postgresql

Can you assist me to figure out what is the problem with my query

```
pg_query($conn, "SELECT DISTINCT reg FROM data WHERE values != '$values'") or die ("Data loading failed: ".pg_last_error());
```

This return all the reg including the reg I don't want to be returned

Comment: show a sample of $values  content ..

Comment: The value of `values` field, what's that?

Comment: Add a check for `NULL` values.

Answer (score 0):

If $values is some sort of list, then it will not work since SQL is expecting one value.

To do that you will either need to use the

```
NOT IN (value1, value2, ...)
```

clause, or join with another table containing your values.

Comment: $value is one value and there are no null values